# Streaming audio from online radio

Tags: java, audio, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I've had a break from programming from a while and slowly but surely I'm coming back into it. I've been looking for a way to stream (and play) audio from an online radiostation (such as FearFM). I've been looking for duplicates and similar questions on Stackoverflow but didn't really found something usefull. I've also looked at Google, but it gives me the impression that the audio support at java is a bit a dark space.

Could anyone point me a direction on how to approach this? Libraries, examples, descriptions.. everything would be appreciated :)

Thanks in advance,

wvd

Comment: So you're looking for something to pick up the live audio from the station? Or just to play some audio?

Comment: Well both. Pick up the live audio and play it directly then.

Comment: That has a high possibility of legal consequences depending on what you do with it. If it's just for personal use, then you're okay, otherwise, you might want to check some of the Fair Use Policies and other such things.

Comment: For now it's just for personal use so I don't really need to worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with media in a Java GUI you could check if JavaFX suppports what you need:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html#package_description

Comment: That won't be the problem. I am mainly looking for an approach on the streaming part.

Comment: AFAIK, JavaFX can help you with the streaming (receiving) part as well.

Answer (score 0):

im just looking for the same as you, i found some usefull stuff in the JMF api, [JMF Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework). in case that you made it already please share code, im looking for that too, send me a PM.